# `Test::More`'s `ok` prints '#' as '\#'

Tags: perl, automated-tests

I'm wondering:
Having a test like `ok($blabla, 'test #' . $i);`, I see output `test \#1` instead of `test #1`.
Why is that, and can I "fix" it in my code?

Using perl 5.18.2...

Example from the Perl debugger:

```perl
main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> use Test::More 'no_plan';

  DB<2> ok(1, 'Test #1');
ok 1 - Test \#1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://testanything.org/tap-specification.html

> DIRECTIVES
>
> Directives are special notes that follow a # on the test line. Only two are  currently defined: TODO and SKIP. Note that these two keywords are not case sensitive.

`#` on the test lines are directives.  It's a TAP spec. Try folowing:

```
0> use Test::More 'no_plan';
1> ok(1, 'Test #1');
ok 1 - Test \#1
$res[0] = 1

2> SKIP: { skip 'description goes here'; ok(1, 'Test #2'); }
ok 2 # skip description goes here
```

Comment: https://testanything.org/tap-version-14-specification.html would be a better link as it is the version of TAP emitted by recent versions of Test::More, and is also the first version of TAP to formalize the `\#` escape sequence.

Answer (score 4):

The `#` is escaped because `#` has a special meaning in TAP, the format Test::More outputs by default.

This is similar to how `<` would be escaped as `&lt;` if you were using a module that was designed to output HTML. When you display the HTML in a client capable of parsing HTML, it gets displayed as `<`.

Similarly, if you display the TAP in a test harness, it should unescape the `\#` for you.

One such test harness is [yath](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Yath). Just install yath then run your test like:

```
yath test -v t/mytest.t
```

You'll see output like this:

```
( LAUNCH )  job  1    t/mytest.t
[  PASS  ]  job  1  + # hi
[  PLAN  ]  job  1    Expected assertions: 1
( MEMORY )  job  1    rss:  21940kB
( MEMORY )  job  1    size: 31480kB
( MEMORY )  job  1    peak: 31480kB
( PASSED )  job  1    t/mytest.t
(  TIME  )  job  1    Startup: 0.02954s | Events: 0.00029s | Cleanup: 0.00326s | Total: 0.03309s

                                Yath Result Summary
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     File Count: 1
Assertion Count: 1
      Wall Time: 0.25 seconds
       CPU Time: 0.43 seconds (usr: 0.10s | sys: 0.03s | cusr: 0.29s | csys: 0.01s)
      CPU Usage: 171%
    -->  Result: PASSED  <--
```

Some older test harnesses (such as the popular [prove](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Prove)) don't fully support the escaping in newer versions of TAP, so don't handle this particular case.

I do recommend yath over prove for myriad reasons though. It provides much cleaner output and allows better control over running parallel tests.

Comment: I re-checked the manual page of `Test::More`: There is no comment about the special meaning of `#`, nor a reference to some `TAP` manual page.

Comment: Test::More does refer to Test::Harness which refers to TAP::Harness which refers you to TAP::Parser which refers to the TAP website which has the TAP spec, so it's *totally* reasonable for the Test::More documentation to never refer to TAP at all.`</sarcasm>`

Comment: Or in other words, yeah, the documentation could be improved with regards to this. But it's also probably not an issue to many people. Seeing `\#` in test output is, at worst, a little ugly.